# Display only highest values from column

Tags: sql

I'm looking to show only the highest values from the 'Rented' alias

```
SELECT
Registration,
COUNT(1) AS RENTED
FROM
I_Booking
GROUP BY Registration
ORDER BY RENTED DESC
```

Not sure where to go from here

Comment: Maximum number of registrations is it what you want to show?

Comment: The Rented column shows how many times each registration number appears.

Just want the rented column to only show me which registration numbers appear the highest number of times.

Comment: What meaning do you put into the definition "only highest values from column" ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following:

```
      SELECT  TAB.Registration, MAX(TAB.RENTED)
      FROM (
        SELECT
            Registration,
            COUNT(1) AS RENTED
            FROM
            I_Booking
            GROUP BY Registration ) TAB
      GROUP BY TAB.Registration
```

Comment: This produces results identical to OP. Are you sure that is an improvement/answer?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `TOP 1` should be enough to leave the highest value from in the 'Rented' column, if that is what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  Registration,
  COUNT(1) AS RENTED
FROM
  I_Booking
GROUP BY Registration
ORDER BY RENTED DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get the Registration which occurred most, use `COUNT(1)` in `ORDER BY` instead of alias :

```
SELECT Registration,COUNT(1) AS RENTED
FROM I_Booking
GROUP BY Registration
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

Comment: Just tried it, still shows values of which aren't the maximum.

Comment: @KromStern: I don't see anything wrong in my answer.